# jQuery's .css method works differently inside and outside of the loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Disclaimer: I am not a front-end engineer, and never was. So, I apologise if I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't wrap my head around whatever I have just experimented in the JavaScript and jQuery.

In my HTML document, I have some `div` elements, a `button` element, and a `<script>` containing:

```js
$("button").click(function(){

    $("div").fadeOut();
    var colour = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random()*255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random()*255) + ")"
    $("div").css("background-color", colour);
    $("div").fadeIn(100);

});
```

and this works as expected. Each and every new click on the `<button>` changes background colour of all the `div` elements, in the enclosing HTML document, setting them to randomly generated RGB values.

If I, however, want to play a little bit and make some "colourful show", by putting all this snippet in a loop, as:

```js
$("button").click(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("div").fadeOut();
        var colour = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random()*255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random()*255) + ")"
        console.log(colour);
        $("div").css("background-color", colour);
        $("div").fadeIn(100);
    }
    
});
```

all the iterations fade out and fade in with the same colour, although, I expect them to be random, and even `console.log(colour)` prints different (random) values.

Note, that I understand, that random can be a pseudo-random, relying on the default seed, but this doesn't matter here.. my problem is having discrete values, in `colour` variable, but not having them worked, as expected, in the `.css` method.

So, why does this (probably - `.css`?) work differently inside and outside of loop?

I am using Google's Chrome, if that matters.

Comment: You do realize that `.fadeOut()` is not a blocking call? You need to do any work that you expect to happen after an asynchronous process is finished in the callback for this process. This applies to Ajax, and it applies to `.fadeOut()`.

Comment: The code works as expected. Those `for` loop iterations are executed synchronously one after another. They don't wait for `fadeIn()` to finish. It only gets started. And the next iteration cancels it and starts another. The browser doesn't even render in between the iterations. So what you're seeing is only the last one. What are you expecting?

Comment: For effects that need to be queued up, such as repeatedly fading out and in a certain element, see https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Comment: Every call in the loop to update the CSS of `$("div")` will update **all** the `<div>` elements on the page. Only the last time through the loop will make any difference.

Comment: So, the `fadeOut()` is not blocking the thread, and right after the end of current iteration, that call is popped off the call stack, i.e. method call is voided. Ok, that's clear; however, why different colours are not set? I have not removed fade ins and outs, completely.. shall I not expect random colours to be set 10 times?

Comment: No, you should not. Every pass through the loop updates every single `<div>` in the document with the same color. The browser will not update them immediately, only when the whole loop is finished.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that it updates all the <div> elements, and that's what I want (I have said this in my question). But I'm struggling to get why only *last time* will make the difference. What if I have `$("div").css("background-color", colour);` only, in my loop (assuming `colour` is a random rgb value).. why it shouldn't set different colours 10 times?

Comment: The browser will not bother to update the DOM until the whole loop completes; it would be a waste of time. If you want an effect like that, use `setTimeout()` to space out your DOM updates.

Comment: Aha.. that's a different (and a bit clearer) story, but then comes the question - how and when browser decides to update DOM.. because, logically speaking, and disregarding the thread blocking which I had initially (this I understood), if I only have `.css("background-color", colour);` it seems to me, that it should work.

Comment: @tao and Tomalak, thank you for shedding light on the thread-blocking part.

Comment: Ref: *"shall I not expect random colours to be set 10 times"*. The color **is set** each and every time. All those 10 times. But the browser doesn't run a `requestAnimationFrame` in between them. Why would it? It's running the code as requested, as it's synchronous code. Then it goes ahead and renders. So when it's finaly told: *"hey, here's something for you to render!".... It just gets the last value.

Comment: @tao and based on **what** that "hey, here's something for you to render!" happens? what event invokes that? what if I'll make `setTimeout` sleep between iterations? why that would change browser's behaviour? I'd be very thankful to have answers on these details, and I'm sorry, if I'm very details-oriented.. I just want to understand **how** exactly things work here.

Comment: The fact that the synchronous code ended execution. Synchronous code is render blocking. To perform renders during it, you have to explicitly call [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). But to answer your specific question: what triggers that: it's about jQuery implementation. I don't know exactly how `fadeOut()` works internally. I'm guessing it uses native JS methods to change opacity (applying style to the element) and then it removes it once it got to 0, in a callback.

Comment: JavaScript is *single threaded* - it can only do one thing at a time, and that *includes* redrawing the UI.  So while your loop is running, it's not updating the UI - when your loop/code/function stops, it's not doing anything else, so can update the UI.

Comment: @tao So, if I get it correct, there are two answers on my question: 1) `fadeOut()` is blocking, and after each iteration, all the story of the "if" block starts from the beginning (I know saw in your edit, that you don't know this for sure, but ok, let's leave this for others); 2) even if I remove the fade out/in lines, and leave only `.css`, until the synchronous/sequential execution of a particular thread is not completed (I may sound a bit server-side programmer now, but you get the idea), browser does **NOT** render the DOM. Thank you.

Comment: In fact, `fadeOut()` is not, really, blocking. It sets `opacity` to `0` on the element while also setting an opacity transition so it animates. And also queues a removal of the element at the end of that transition. Now, I don't know if the deletion is queued using a `setTimeout` (unlikely) or attaching a [ontransitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontransitionend) handler on the element (more likely), and whether or not jQuery checks if the transition was performed or overridden, I can't tell you without looking in source....

Comment: ... but as soon as those operations have ended (setting opacity, opacity transition and queuing the removal), there's no call to `requestAnimationFrame`, as there's more synchronous code to run (the next iteration).

Comment: @tao the element is not *removed* at the end of `fadeOut` - otherwise you wouldn't be able to `fadeIn` it back.

Comment: @freedomn-m, my bad. You're correct. it's not deleted. Its `display` is set to `none` instead. My jQuery is getting rusty. I guess I should be happy about that.